# Why doesn't the up/down slider bar work? Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

the slider does not work, it draws it, but the command does not work. I tried all the methods on the Internet, and they do not work.
I can’t understand the very essence of the problem, tk. tkinter itself does not throw errors, and neither does Python itself. I read the documentation and didn't see anything useful.

```
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from json import load, dump

windowset = Tk()

def _save():
    messagebox.showinfo('Settings Answer', 'Changes saved')

class _settings():
    global combo
    global combo2
    global combo3
    global combo4
    global combo5
    global combo6
    global combo7
    global combo8
    global combo9
    global combo10
    global combo11
    global combo12
    global combo13
    global combo14
    def _replace_bg():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_background"] = '{}'.format(combo.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_banner():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["_banner"] = '{}'.format(combo2.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_entryip():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["_entryip"] = '{}'.format(combo3.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_entryipbg():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["_entryipbg"] = '{}'.format(combo4.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_entrymac():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["_entrymac"] = '{}'.format(combo5.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_entrymacbg():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["_entrymacbg"] = '{}'.format(combo6.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_entrynumber():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["_entrynumber"] = '{}'.format(combo7.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_entrynumberbg():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["_entrynumberbg"] = '{}'.format(combo8.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_banner_ip():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["_ip"] = '{}'.format(combo9.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_banner_mac():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["_mac"] = '{}'.format(combo10.get()) 
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_banner_number_phone():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["_numberphone"] = '{}'.format(combo11.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_button_ip():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["schemabuttons"]["_butt_ip"] = '{}'.format(combo12.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config', 'w') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_button_mac():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["schemabuttons"]["_butt_mac"] = '{}'.format(combo13.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    def _replace_color_button_number_phone():
        try:
            with open(r'files\config') as f:
                data=load(f)
            data["MainWindow"]["_colortext"]["schemabuttons"]["_butt_number"] = '{}'.format(combo14.get())
        finally:
            with open(r'files\config') as f2:
                dump(data, f2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            _save()
    windowset.title('Settings')
    #windowset.iconbitmap(r'files\Settings.ico')
    windowset.configure(background='black')
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(windowset)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')
    listbox = Listbox(windowset, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    try:
        try:
            # Block 1
            combo = Combobox(windowset)
            banner = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Choose a background color', 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='Black', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            )
            )
            combo['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            combo.current(2)
            butt = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set BackGround', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_bg
            )
            #
            # Block 2
            lbl = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange text color of `Spider-Breaking` banner', 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            )
            )
            combo2 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo2['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt2 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_banner, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            #
            # Block 3
            lbl2 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange text color `Entry IP-Address`', 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial', 
                                    10
                            )
            )
            combo3 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo3['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt3 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_entryip, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            #
            # Block 4
            lbl3 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange color `Entry Background IP-Address`', 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial', 
                                    10
                            )
            )
            combo4 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo4['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt4 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_entryipbg, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            #
            # Block 5
            lbl4 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange text color `Entry MAC-Address`', 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial', 
                                    10
                            )
            )
            combo5 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo5['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt5 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_entrymac, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            #
            # Block 6
            lbl5 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange color `Entry Background MAC-Address`', 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial', 
                                    10
                            )
            )
            combo6 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo6['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt6 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_entrymacbg, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            # 
            # Block 7
            lbl6 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange text color `Entry Number Phone`', 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial', 
                                    10
                            )
            )
            combo7 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo7['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt7 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_entrynumber, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            #
            # Block 8
            lbl7 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange color `Entry Background Number Phone`', 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial', 
                                    10
                            )
            )
            combo8 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo8['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt8 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_entrynumberbg, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            #
            # Block 9
            lbl8 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange color banner `IP`', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black'
            )
            combo9 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo9['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt9 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_banner_ip, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            #
            # Block 10
            lbl9 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange color banner `MAC`', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black'
            )
            combo10 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo10['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt10 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_banner_mac, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            #
            # Block 11
            lbl10 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange color banner `Number Phone`', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black'
            )
            combo11 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo11['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt11 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_banner_number_phone, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            #
            # Block 12
            lbl11 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange color button `IP`', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black'
            )
            combo12 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo12['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt12 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_button_ip, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            #
            # Block 13
            lbl12 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange color button `MAC`', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black'
            )
            combo13 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo13['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt13 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            command=_replace_color_button_mac, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            # 
            # Block 14
            lbl13 = Label(
                            windowset, 
                            text='\nChange color button `Number Phone`', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ), 
                            fg='white', 
                            bg='black'
            )
            combo14 = Combobox(windowset)
            combo14['values'] = ('pink', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'yellow')
            butt14 = Button(
                            windowset, 
                            text='Set', 
                            font=(
                                    'Arial Bold', 
                                    10
                            ),
                            command=_replace_color_banner_number_phone, 
                            width=9, 
                            height=0
            )
            #
            #/MAIN\
            __all__block = [combo, banner, butt,combo2, lbl, butt2,combo3, lbl2, butt3,combo4, lbl3, butt4,combo5, lbl4, butt5,combo6, lbl5, butt6,combo7, lbl6, butt7,combo8, lbl7, butt8,combo9, lbl8, butt9,combo10, lbl9, butt10,
                            combo11, lbl10, butt11,combo12,lbl11,butt12,combo13,lbl12,butt13,combo14, lbl13, butt14]
            for i in __all__block:
                listbox.insert('end', i.pack())
            listbox.pack()
            #/END\
        except Exception as Ex:
            print(Ex)
    finally:
        scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
        windowset.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre], reduce your code to a minimum that still runs when copy and paste to reproduce your issue. Community members that are willing to help might refuse to work through a block of code. Also note the community standards for [ask] and note the recommendation to skip such questions in [answer].

Comment: A Tkinter Listbox contains lines of text - and absolutely nothing else.  You seem to be trying to insert all of your widgets into the Listbox, which is just nonsense.  (Actually you're inserting the result of calling `.pack()` on each widget, which is None.)

Comment: create `minimal working code` with your problem. I don't even see where you use slider because code is too long.

Comment: what methods did you try? You should describe it - so we will not have to suggest solutions which don't work for you.

Comment: if you put code in class then you could use `self.` instead of `global` . Besides putting code directly in class also is strange. You could use normal function for this. And you could use one `try` with `except` and `finally` - but frankly I don't know why you need it all this `try/except` for this.

Comment: the main problem is that `listbox` can keep only text, not widgets. You may have to use `Canvas` with `Frame` and add widgets to this frame - and later scroll this frame on canvas. See example on my GitHub [furas / python-examples / tkinter / scrolled-frame-canvas](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this block of code:

```
for i in __all__block:
    listbox.insert('end', i.pack())
```

It is calling `pack()` on every widget created in the prior block of code. `pack()` returns `None`, so  you are inserting `None` inside the listbox over and over and over. Inserting `None` results in nothing getting added to the listbox.

The listbox can only scroll text items added with the `insert` method. It won't scroll widgets added using `pack`, `place`, or `grid`.